# Error: java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin, on jenkins in docker

Tags: java, docker, jenkins

I have installed docker then java image then jenkins image, now installing its dependencies, gives following error in logs, any Idea how can it be resolved, as I am from rails background so don't have much knowledge about java error and exceptions, please provide suggestions.

```
May 31, 2020 9:41:30 AM hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run
INFO: Starting the installation of Pipeline: Job on behalf of admin
May 31, 2020 9:41:32 AM hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration download
INFO: Downloading Pipeline: Job
May 31, 2020 9:41:33 AM hudson.PluginManager dynamicLoad
INFO: Attempting to dynamic load /var/jenkins_home/plugins/workflow-job.jpi
May 31, 2020 9:41:33 AM hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run
SEVERE: Failed to install Pipeline: Job
java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1893)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1651)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install workflow-job plugin
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:874)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:813)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1889)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipeline: Job v2.39 failed to load.
 - You must update Jenkins from v2.60.3 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.
 - Pipeline: API v2.40 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:626)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:864)
    ... 7 more
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Which Jenkins version did you install?
It seems like plugins not supporting on outdated Jenkins version.
Try to skip plugin installation from 'Getting Started' and install them later.

Also, you can try to use official Jenkins docker images.
https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/12/10/the-official-Docker-image/

Comment: "JENKINS_VERSION=2.60.3",

Comment: its the latest jenkins version available on docker, i have checked their website.

Comment: I see `You must update Jenkins from v2.60.3 to v2.138.4 or later to run this plugin.`. 
I think you can either try to install version above '2.138.4' or skip installation from the starting section.  
I recommend you to use latest Jenkins version, it has lots of vulnerability fixes.

Comment: Can you check the link that I attached? There is 'jenkins' and 'jenkins/jenkins' docker images. You should use 'jenkins/jenkins' image.
https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/tags

Comment: now pulling another docker image for jenkins "docker pull jenkins/jenkins:centos" and remove previous one.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue and tried with v2.60.3 and other version as well.

LTS version works and installs plugin.

```
$ docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts

$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name myjenkins jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

there's deprecation notice in the page as following https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins?tab=description

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and it's because there was old jenkins configuration in folder "/home/user/.jenkins/" , just delete it o backup it, in order when you new Jenkins Installation start, it going to create a new ".jenkins/" folder with empty conf.

And don't forget that you really has deinstalled old jenkins version.